# Image encoding compatible with ORB when using cvbridge C++

Tags: opencv, orb

I am receiving images from a ROS Publisher Node. A Subscriber node receives the image, converts it using cvbridge into a Mat object with MONO8 encoding. Then ORB feature detector detects the features in this image. But the problem is the ORB doesn't detect any thing. The same code is working when i read the same image from memory using imread command. I think this is due to MONO8 encoding. So which encoding is compatible with ORB feature detection in Opencv.?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, actually i was doing mistake, ORB doesn't work if two images are same. I started giving it the different images and now its working fine